# Synchronizing RX .NET Subscribe by CorrelationId

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I'm trying to write something similar to Sagas using RX.NET. I've came across a simple issue and I don't know what the best way is to sychronize states by correlation id. I have simple EventAggregator which listens for some events and it can be notified from multiple threads so I cannot assume that subscribe is always called on the same thread so there is a possibility that the first notification will update the state and in the meantime another notification will receive old state and work with it so I have to synchronize it. I have simplified my scenario to something like below. I could lock the whole subscribe by some object id dependent but it doesn't seem right. What is RX way of doing it?

```
 public interface IEventAggregator
    {
        IObservable<T> GetEvent<T>() where T : Event;
    }

    public class EventAggregator : IEventAggregator
    {
        Subject<Event> _sub = new Subject<Event>();

        public IObservable<T> GetEvent<T>() where T : Event
        {
            return _sub.OfType<T>();
        }

        public void Notify<T>(T ev) where T : Event
        {
            _sub.OnNext(ev);
        }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    }

    public class State
    {
        public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IStateRepository
    {
        State Get(string id);
    }

    public class ProcessManager
    {
        private readonly IStateRepository _stateRepository;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public ProcessManager(IStateRepository stateRepository, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _stateRepository = stateRepository;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            eventAggregator.GetEvent<Event>()
             .Select(x => _stateRepository.Get(x.CorrelationId))
             .Subscribe(state =>
             {
                 // -do something with state like write or read;
                 // - state should be unique per correlation id.
                 // - this block should be synchronized.
             });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `.Publish`? It will connect only once to your source but ensure that each subscription to the connectable observable is handled one at a time.

Comment: hey, could you show me an example?